# how can I add .js or .cpp before do vim showcut key gf?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vim

In a programing language like nodejs, when we use `require` function, it is not needed to add `.js` extension. Like this:

```
var Assert = require('./app_base');
```

In vim, when I do `gf`, it said in this path can't find `app_base`.It finds it if I mention `app_base.js` not `app_base`.

I don't want add `.js` in the end of `./app_base` like `./app_base.js`but I want find `app_base.js` when I do `gf`, how can I do this？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add one of these in your `.vimrc` :

**1. Setting it Globally:**

`set suffixesadd+=.js,.cpp`

see `:help suffixesadd`. You can also use the short form `sua+`

**2. Filetype specific options using Autocommands:**

`autocmd FileType javascript,coffee setlocal suffixesadd+=.js,.json,.coffee`

Comment: It's probably better to do `set sua+=.js,.cpp` and perhaps even wrap this in filetype autocommand.

Comment: @AndyRk It's probably even better to avoid piling duplicates: `let &sua=join(uniq(sort(split(&sua, ','))), ',')`.  Also you can avoid `autocmd FileType` by moving the command to a `ftplugin`.